# Launch-time initialization in Next.js static/exported site

Tags: next.js, static-site

I'm trying to use Next to power an Electron app. [electron-next](https://github.com/leo/electron-next) uses Next's static site mode for its production build, which calls `getInitialProps` at build-time, rather than launch-time.

**start.js** (initially rendered page)

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Start({date}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Date is {date}</div> {/* <- will always be the build time */}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>Take me to the About page</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

Start.getInitialProps = () => {
  return {
    date: "" + new Date()
  }
}
```

Interestingly, using `Link` to navigate elsewhere does, in fact, result in a dynamic `getInitialProps` call.

**about.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function About({date}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Date is {date}</div> {/* <- will be the time the link was clicked */}
      <div>Important info about this app</div>
    </div>
  )
}

About.getInitialProps = () => {
  return {
    date: "" + new Date()
  }
}
```

Is there a non-hacky way to get dynamic behavior for the initial route? I imagine this would have plenty of use cases in static sites, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using `getInitialProps` at all. Instead, I'm using a React hook. It works basically like this:

```
async function useModel() {
  const modelRef = useRef(null)


  // This hook will render at build-time by Next.js's static site, in which
  // case the conditional loading of the model will never happen.
  //
  // At startup-time, it will be re-renderered on the Electron renderer thread,
  // at which time, we'll actually want to load data.
  if (process.browser && !modelRef.current) {
    const m = new Model()
    await m.init() // <- Assumed to have some async fetching logic
    modelRef.current = m
  }

  return modelRef.current
}
```

Then, the top-level component can easily use the presence of the model to determine what to do next:

```
function Start() {
  const model = useModel()

  if (!model) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } else {
    return <MyProperUI model={model} />
  }
}
```

Or, you could easily rig it up to show an unpopulated default UI, or whatever.

So basically, use `getInitialProps` for code you want to run *exactly once*, server-side/build-time or client-side. Otherwise, use other means of initialization. As seen here, hooks allow for this with pretty minimal boilerplate.